# FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain when trying to login with Google

Tags: firebase, google-authentication, firebase-authentication

I've setup Google login in my Firebase app (I'm using the new Firebase console), but each time I try with Google, I get the following error:

```
#<NSError:0x11f0625a0, description="An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.", code=17999, domain="FIRAuthErrorDomain", userInfo={"NSUnderlyingError"=>#<NSError:0x122278130, description="The operation couldn’t be completed. (FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain error 3.)", code=3, domain="FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain", userInfo={"FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey"=>{"message"=>"", "errors"=>[{"reason"=>"invalid", "message"=>"", "domain"=>"global"}], "code"=>400}}>, "error_name"=>"ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR", "NSLocalizedDescription"=>"An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information."}>
```

I don't really know where yo go from here, since there's no message in the message field. Any guesses on what this could be?

I've recently migrated to the new version of Firebase btw. I'm using the new SDK in my iOS app. Furthermore, I setup Google authentication a week before I migrated. I'm not sure if any keys have been overwritten in the migration. How do I check if I have the right keys in my console vs my GoogleService plist file?